# How to guarantee a function is bounded near the origin analyzing curves passing through it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider a **continuous** function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

If I want to guarantee $f$ is bounded near the origin what kind of curves passing through the origin do I have to analyze? I know from counterexamples that it is not sufficient to consider lines...

Ps: you can assume $f$ is smooth if you want.

Comment: By analysing special paths you usually prove that the function has *not* certain properties.